# How to extract data from JSON with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I use the Alamofire library this way:

```
 Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://www.somesample.com/getData.php", parameters: ["user":"charles"]).responseJSON{jsonData in

var theData = jsonData.result.value
```

If I debug print the theData variable, it throws something like:

```
    [
  {
    "userId" : "61",
    "userPicture" : "147884767502.jpg",
    "wasId" : "80",
    "favorite" : "0",
    "message" : "how are you?",
    "username" : "paco",
    "date" : "13\/10\/2015 03:44PM",
    "userPhrase" : "hello"
    "repliesNumber" : 2
  },
  {
    "userId" : "3",
    "userPicture" : "149181897286.jpg",
    "wasId" : "5",
    "favorite" : "0",
    "message" : "let's go!",
    "username" : "loliFlower",
    "date" : "30\/08\/2015 07:48PM",
    "userPhrase" : "ciiiii!",
    "repliesNumber" : 3
  }
]
```

I usually use SwiftyJSON so I write (even I use a for loop to walk to every single index of the array the SwiftyJSON makes:

```
var myData = JSON(theData.result.value)

print(myData[0]["username"].stringValue)
```

But what if I don't want to use SwiftyJSON library anymore? **what is the native way to do this?**

Comment: Even SwiftyJSON has an example of what you usually would have to do: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#why-is-the-typical-json-handling-in-swift-not-good  SwiftyJSON is just a convenience wrapper around this

Comment: The issue is that it don't really know what is what Alamofire returns. In SwiftyJSON documentation says NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data --> I guess the is NSData ...)

Comment: `responseJSON` gives you an `AnyObject` which comes from `NSJSONSerialization` (see [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ResponseSerialization.swift#L271)), which you can use to initialise the SwiftyJSON type: `JSON(jsonObject)` according to [this](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L87). The requirements for this method are met exactly for the `NSJSONSerialization` (no surprise really).

Comment: Or you could use the method from Alamofire that returns the raw data and then call `NSJSONSerialization.json...` yourself according to the example in SwiftyJSON. Or you can also pass the data to SwiftyJSON, which would do this for you (see [here](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L68-L78))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you use code generation to create native models out of the json response, this will save your time of parsing by hand and reduce the risk of errors due to mistaken keys, all elements will be accessible by model properties, this will be purely native and the models will make more sense rather checking the keys. Check http://www.json4swift.com and let me know if you require further help in initiating the object from your json response. (make sure you enter the actual json response and not the printed object as that in your question)